# Load values from database using SQL and repeater control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I've got a database file with "Champions League" groups. Table with information looks for example like this: "Team: Real Madrid, group: A; Team: Manchester UTD, group: A; Team: Chelsea London, Group: A; Team: Arsenal London, group: A; Team: Fc Barcelona, Group B; Team: Manchester City, group: B; Team: Atletico Madrid, group: B; Team: Juventus, group: B;" etc. At this moment, to receive values from database I'am using 8 repeaters (each one for every group) to rendering html tables for groups, and code behind:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=D:/VisualWebSitesProject/EURO-PILKA/bazyDanych/ligi.mdb";
    con.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From ChampionsLeague WHERE Group LIKE A ORDER By Points DESC", con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    groupA.DataSource = ds;
    groupA.DataBind();
    con.Close();

    con.Open()
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter da2 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    da2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From ChampionsLeague WHERE Group LIKE B ORDER By Points DESC", con);
    da2.Fill(ds2);
    groupB.DataSource = ds2;
    groupB.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```

and the same for the rest of groups. Everythink works fine, but i'am wondering: Is a better way to do that ?. Without using so many repeaters, or datasets ?. I'am worrying about this, because i want also creating a "World Cup" groups (8 repeaters), and "Europa League" groups (12 repeaters) and I think page will loading very slow..

Repeater construction:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="groupA" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <div class="wygladNaglowekTabele wygladNaglowekTabeleOnload">GROUP A</div>
                        <table id="liga" class="wygladTabelaLiga">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="szerokosc1 color3">Lp.</td><td class="szerokosc2 color3 wysrodkuj">DRUZYNA</td><td class="szerokosc1 color3">Lm</td><td class="szerokosc1 color3">B</td><td class="szerokosc1 color3">Pts</td>
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="szerokosc1 color2"><%#Container.ItemIndex +1%></td><td class="szerokosc2 color2"><%#Eval("Team")%></td><td class="szerokosc1 color2"><%#Eval("LiczbaMeczy")%></td><td class="szerokosc1 color2"><%#Eval("LiczbaGoliStrzelonych")%></td><td class="szerokosc1 color2"><%#Eval("Points")%></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                         <tr>
                            <td class="szerokosc1 color"><%#Container.ItemIndex +1%></td><td class="szerokosc2 color"><%#Eval("Team")%></td><td class="szerokosc1 color"><%#Eval("LiczbaMeczy")%></td><td class="szerokosc1 color"><%#Eval("LiczbaGoliStrzelonych")%></td><td class="szerokosc1 color"><%#Eval("Points")%></td>
                        </tr>
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Thank You for any advise !. And I'am sorry for my english..

Answer (score 0):

You can get all groups in one call and create final html tags programmically in one StringBuilder, then put stringBuilder strings to a control like asp:Litral